# Fastest way to add a deque onto the end of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, deque

This question is about speed.

I am using a function in the openCV libraries (in FaceRecognizer class) which requires the input of a vector. I need to build this vector by combining several deque. Are there any faster ways other than iterating through the deque and pushing back each element to the vector?

**Some info about the deque**: it is a deque of 15 elements where I continuously push_back and if it has 16+ elements I pop_front. Order matters.

Alternatively I could change the deque's to vectors if that might speed up everything, but from what I understand that will be slow when I delete the first element of the vector when it reaches size 16.

Comment: Construct the vector from a pair of iterators?

Comment: If it's got only 15 elements, the vector won't be noticably slower than the deque. If you don't even *know* if it will be slow, then find out first, then ask question.

Comment: My suggestion is to compute the size of the vector and to call `vector::reserve` to prevent container reallocation.

Comment: seems like a ring buffer problem to me.

Comment: So your last paragraph is unrelated to the question about appending deques to the end of vectors, right? Because it is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fastest way to add a deque onto the end of a vector?

Getting the size of the deque is possible in constant time (as for all STL containers), then reserve space in the vector to limit memory management overhead to a single allocation, finally move the elements out of the deque into the vector:

```
// std::vector v, std::deque d
v.reserve(v.size() + d.size());
std::move(std::begin(d), std::end(d), std::back_inserter(v));
d.clear(); // or reuse in some way
```

If you intend to append multiple containers to the vector, consider `reserve`ing the complete storage necessary at once.

Watch for `std::bad_alloc` exceptions if the amount of data is huge. In that case using contiguous storage of a vector isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

queue/vector myItem;

```
// Swap the position to the back, if it's first use 0 if you like
myItem[position].swap(myItem.back());
myItem.pop_back();
```

Then it's not reallocating the entire list when you remove from the front.